# passing information from Sharepoint to Immersive Sharepoint App

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I have created an custom add entry app to sharepoint. It all works however currently the list it works on is hard coded.

I want a way to pass the list I want to add an entry to to the application. I thought this would be done via Query String, but I can not figure out how it works.

In the applications AppManifest.xml I have changed the query string to:

```
{StandardTokens}&source={source}
```

Ideally, it would be better if it was something like &list=listname but my thinking here was that I could get the listname from the source url..

I then make a link in my sharepoint site to point to:

```
myurl.com/sites/codev/CustomEntryApp/default.aspx?source={source}
```

But this is incorrect, it doesn't update the {source} place holder like I thought it would..

If I hard code the url:

```
myurl.com/sites/codev/CustomEntryApp/default.aspx?ListToWorkWith=ListName
```

This doesn't carry on the query string..

Comment: Have you tried using a capital S in Source?

Comment: yes I just tried. and it didn't seem to work still

Comment: So I just realised that {Source} doesn't work on a Start Page.. Im just wondering how I will send a parameter to my sharepoint app? I want my app to work on multiple lists, and be chosen dependent on the variable I send it..